# Steps to push simple Java rest api to Docker using VSTS CI

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I have create simple rest endpoint which will return Hello world for Get operation. I have created docker file to push the

```
FROM openjdk:8     

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

COPY /SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/docker-spring.jar

EXPOSE 8085

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring.jar"]
```

when I try to run it using VSTS, I am getting following error:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for openjdk:8
2018-07-23T10:51:00.4948836Z  ---> 8c80ddf988c8
2018-07-23T10:51:00.4966564Z Step 2/6 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app

2018-07-23T10:51:14.7731002Z  ---> Running in 2242c1baadde
2018-07-23T10:51:16.5140472Z Removing intermediate container 2242c1baadde
2018-07-23T10:51:16.5163574Z  ---> b8dba30e6e9c
2018-07-23T10:51:16.5179644Z Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /usr/local/app


2018-07-23T10:51:17.8398811Z Removing intermediate container 47a1a4cf9a23
2018-07-23T10:51:17.8418756Z  ---> 9fc455c476e0


2018-07-23T10:51:17.8437188Z Step 4/6 : COPY /SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/docker-spring.jar
2018-07-23T10:51:17.8457664Z ***COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder484497191/SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar: no such file or directory
2018-07-23T10:51:17.8581142Z ##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder484497191/SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar: no such file or directory***
2018-07-23T10:51:17.8659023Z ##[error]/usr/local/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
```

AM i missing any steps? Please help me out

Comment: COPY's dest is supposed to be a dir, I think. Try this: `COPY /SpringRest/target/docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/`

Comment: Also verify that the source file does indeed exist at that location (and is readable by that user). Do you _really_ have top-level dir `SpringRest`? Somehow I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, I've  top level directory SpringRest. under which I have DockerFile, Source and Target folder

Comment: whether Dockerfile and Jar file needs to be placed in same folder to work as per expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FROM openjdk:8     

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

RUN cd /SpringRest/target

COPY docker-spring.jar /usr/local/app/

EXPOSE 8085

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring.jar"]
```

---

```
FROM openjdk:8     

WORKDIR /SpringRest/target

EXPOSE 8085

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","docker-spring.jar"]
```

Comment: Is there anything else in /usr/local/app ? I mean for now you can make /SpringRest/target as your WORKDIR

Comment: @Girish Since you problem solved, you can mark the answer.